# Left and right align inside one TiKZ rectangular node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to create a PID controller block diagram similar to the one [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PID_en.svg). At the moment my diagram looks as depicted below. What I still need is to right-and-left align the text inside the rectangular nodes, i.e. I'd like the letters P, I, D to be left and the equations right aligned. How do I accomplish that? Also, could you please tell me how to make the circle a little smaller?

[image]

```
\tikzstyle{int}=[draw, fill=blue!20, minimum size=2em, text width=2.5cm]
\tikzstyle{sum}=[draw, fill=blue!20, shape=circle, node distance=2.5cm]
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm,auto,>=latex']
        \node [int] (kp) {P $k_p e(t)$};
        \node [int] (ki) [below of=kp] {I $k_i \int{e(t)dt}$};
        \node [int] (kd) [below of=ki] {D $k_d \frac{e(t)}{dt}$};
        \node [sum] (sum) [right of=ki] {$\sum$};
        \node [coordinate] (joint1) [left of=ki, node distance=2cm]{};
        \node [coordinate] (begin) [left of=joint1, node distance=2cm]{};
        \node [coordinate] (end) [right of=sum, node distance=2cm]{};
        \draw[-] (begin) -- node {$e(t)$} (joint1);
        \draw[->] (joint1) |- (kp.west);
        \draw[->] (joint1) -- (ki);
        \draw[->] (joint1) |- (kd);
        \draw[->] (kp.east) -| node [pos=0.95] {$+$} (sum.north);
        \draw[->] (ki.east) -- node [pos=0.8] {$+$} (sum.west);
        \draw[->] (kd.east) -| node [pos=0.95] {$+$} (sum.south);
        \draw[->] (sum.east) -- (end);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please make sure that the code is compilable. Ideally by making it a small, self-contained document, but at least by including all necessary definitions (the `sum` and `int` styles are missing here).

Comment: Right, sorry, corrected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `\hfill` between the letter and the equation to get simultaneous left and right adjustment. This only works if you specify the `text width` explicitly, though (as you've done in your code).

For decreasing the size of the circle, you'll have to decrease the `inner sep` (which is set to `2pt` by default). If you want the node to be smaller still, you'll have to choose a smaller font size (using `font=\small`, for instance), or scale the node using `scale=<value>`.

Here's a minimal example (this is also the preferred form of posting code like yours in a question, since it saves people the trouble of guessing the required libraries/packages, and makes sure that the code is actually complete):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{int}=[draw, fill=blue!20, minimum size=2em, text width=2.5cm]
\tikzstyle{sum}=[draw, fill=blue!20, shape=circle, inner sep=1pt, node distance=2.5cm]
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm,auto,>=latex']
        \node [int] (kp) {P\hfill$k_p e(t)$};
        \node [int] (ki) [below of=kp] {I\hfill$k_i \int{e(t)dt}$};
        \node [int] (kd) [below of=ki] {D\hfill$k_d \frac{e(t)}{dt}$};
        \node [sum] (sum) [right of=ki] {$\sum$};
        \node [coordinate] (joint1) [left of=ki, node distance=2cm]{};
        \node [coordinate] (begin) [left of=joint1, node distance=2cm]{};
        \node [coordinate] (end) [right of=sum, node distance=2cm]{};
        \draw[-] (begin) -- node {$e(t)$} (joint1);
        \draw[->] (joint1) |- (kp.west);
        \draw[->] (joint1) -- (ki);
        \draw[->] (joint1) |- (kd);
        \draw[->] (kp.east) -| node [pos=0.95] {$+$} (sum.north);
        \draw[->] (ki.east) -- node [pos=0.8] {$+$} (sum.west);
        \draw[->] (kd.east) -| node [pos=0.95] {$+$} (sum.south);
        \draw[->] (sum.east) -- (end);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Forgotten to drop a human-to-human thank you before (apart of accepting the answer), so: Thanks Jake, that helped!